# ASP.NET Drop Down list , the button function not firing after the first click

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASP.Net Dropdownlist , on changing the value of drop down list and clicking the button it is not sending an upadted value to the New.aspx

> 

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_test" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_test_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem>First Item</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Second Item</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Third Item</asp:ListItem>

        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdf_ddl" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_test" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>



using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class Test_DropDown : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string passValue = ddl_test.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string val = hdf_ddl.Value.ToString();
        btn_test.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('New.aspx?ddlValue=" + val + "', 'OpenPopWindow','left=250,top=100,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1');return false;");
        //btn_test.OnClientClick = "window.open('New.aspx?ddlValue=" + val + "', 'OpenPopWindow','left=250,top=100,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1');return false;";


    }
    protected void ddl_test_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        hdf_ddl.Value = ddl_test.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the following code:

```
btn_test.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('New.aspx?ddlValue=" + val + "', 'OpenPopWindow','left=250,top=100,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1');return false;");
```

to your Page_Load event

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the assignment of OnClientClick is commented out.

Secondly, if you want the button to display the value after it has been selected, register OnClientClick in the ddl_test_SelectedIndexChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have new window opened after the first button click you should register onclick event handler not in the `Button1_Click` method becase `Button1_Click` is executed only after click on the button. You can modify your page load method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string val = hdf_ddl.Value.ToString();
    btn_test.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('New.aspx?ddlValue=" + val + "',  OpenPopWindow','left=250,top=100,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1');return false;");
}
```

But better way to do what you want is to avoid postbacks on dropdown selection and implement new window opening on client side.

Answer (score 0):

You could send the windowopen function to the page via the [registerstartupscript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx?ppud=4) method.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to open a popup windows after the postback has happened. This can be performed with the use of injecting the script into the page. Basically you use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock and inject the popup window script using that method. Also, make sure that the last parameter which I think is to include the script tags is true which will execute the script as soon as the JavaScript code is injected into the page.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the implementation:

```
protected void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string script =
        "window.open('New.aspx','OpenPopWindow','width=500,height=500');";

    ClientScriptManager clientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript; 

    if(!clientScriptManager.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("OpenWindow"))
    {
        clientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(_Default), "OpenWindow", script, true);     
    }


}
```